# Updating to latest gcc and g++ on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, gcc, g++

I recently tried to downgrade to gcc 4.7 since a cfd code I was working on didn't compile with the latest gcc version. But after many errors and the code still not compiling I gave up and would like to go back to the latest gcc and g++ compilers however it seems I may have messed something up.

When I do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc 
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
sudo apt-get install gcc-6.2 g++-6.2
```

or even gcc-5.1 g++-5.1 for that matter, it gives me the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-6.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-6.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-6.2'
E: Unable to locate package g++-6.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'g++-6.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-6.2'
```

and I also tried doing this before

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-6.2 g++-6.2
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Finally when I just do

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
```

I know I still need to install and configure alternatives but doing that doesn't work either as follows

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5.3 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5.3 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 30
sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 30
sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

Sorry this ended up quite long and please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

**EDIT:**  I actually got it to work by changing gcc-5.3 to gcc-5 in the above code as that seemed to be what it's called in usr/bin. I will keep it for future reference if anyone faces the same problem.

Comment: AFAIK gcc and g++ don't install as update-alternatives by default - instead, the `gcc` and `g++` dependency packages install direct links to the default dependencies, like `/usr/bin/g++ -> g++-5`. Have you tried simply reinstalling the `gcc` and `g++` packages?

Comment: One way of avoiding this type of issues is to create a VM and install the old compiler version in there.

Comment: This hotfix can be fixed in the installation Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done gcc is already the newest version (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.

Answer (score 7):

Run the following commands in sequence.  I was getting same error.  This worked for me.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-snapshot
sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6
```

Comment: What does the gcc-snapshot exactly do? How can I remove the previous gcc version (4.8.4) ?

Comment: remove the sudo and this works within a docker container.

Comment: @abunickabhi you can change the version of gcc being used with the following command after you run the commands above: update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-6. Also, if you have multiple versions of gcc installed you can switch between them with the following "sudo update-alternatives --config gcc"

Answer (score 0):

apt-get update has to be run so your computer will access the repository that has just been added, thus making its contents available to you.  If you do not run it then your computer is not aware that it has that repositorys info available to it